# How to Make a Portable Internet USB Device with Wifi Capability to Send all the data first to some particular device and then to other clients?

Tags: router, switch, packet, wifi-transfer

I have a portable internet USB device which can also throw wifi signals. All type of clients are usually connected to this device through wifi including PCs and Android devices. Is there any way that when a client device requests any website or any other query from the USB internet device, the data in reply is first sent to some other Device, be it a PC or Android devcie, and then to the original requester?

Comment: What is this "portable internet USB device", can you be more specific? And in other words what you want it to packet capture the users connected to this device, or to just see what they are doing in general? I can almost guarantee your "portable internet USB device" does not have this capability, this is something that would probably require much higher end hardware to accomplish. Of course, if we were to know what the device is, what you want the information sent to, and how many users/devices we are talking about, the answer may change.

Comment: @acejavelin   Please visit this [Link](https://www.zong.com.pk/mbb/4g_wingle.php). It has all the info on the device.

Comment: Secondly, i want information to be sent to one of the connected devices in the network. And there are 3-4 devices connected at one time mostly.

Comment: Well, this is a dumb USB/WiFi adapter, the only this could work would be with additional equipment... You would need a higher-end router that can use the WiFi as its WAN connection, the creator a new WiFi network for users to connect to, then it would need to be able to setup a monitor of the WiFi network and a separate PC would need to be hardwired to the router to do packet captures. This is not possible with the existing equipment, nor is it a simple setup with proper enterprise grade equipment.

Comment: @acejavelin OK, Thanks. I had another idea that if we could somehow change the current firmware in this device with the one i could modify. Is it possible?

Comment: I am not familiar with this device and it doesn't appear to be open source (it is not in the OpenWRT or DD-WRT hardware databases), so that is unlikely. USB dongles like this are typically closed source and not easily modifiable, this isn't even a dongle, it just uses USB for power and seems to be a completely self-contained unit.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks Man, for all the help. :)

Comment: sorry I don't have an answer, good luck

Comment: @acejavelin can you please refer this question to someone else who can answer to this.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking me to do by "refer this question to someone else", anyone is more than able to answer it if they have the knowledge or willingness to answer. The problem is you are not really in control of the network other than the capabilities of the device, which seem extremely limited. This device is intended for personal use, and you are trying to use it in a way that an enterprise might, it is just not within your hardware's capabilities.